# hidden Div reappears after page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, razor

I have a hidden div that keeps reappearing for no reason.

The Reappearer;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomethingAction", "WorkSpace", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "true", id = "frmHidden"}))
{
  <div id="theHiddenDiv">
    ...just some textboxes here and a submit button
  </div>
}
```

On another form in the same page I have the following which just toggles button visibility. After I submit this form, theHiddenDiv reappears.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostSomethingAction", "WorkSpace", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "true", id = "frmMainStuff" }))
{
 ...
 <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="toggleVis();" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left">+ something?</a>
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="Go!" name="Command" />
 ...
}
```

the only piece of code changing visibility

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#theHiddenDiv').hide(); 
});

function toggleVis() {
    $('#theHiddenDiv').toggle();
}
```

Comment: maybe the `$('#theHiddenDiv').hide();` is being loaded before the actual div, is it made dynamically?

Comment: After submitting form, it reloads the page and hence div appears in its default mode.

Comment: #theHiddenDiv { display: none; } (or similar) and use JS/CSS to show it instead. Perhaps $('#theHiddenDiv').hide(); doesn't run because of some other JS code breaking earlier on the page.

Comment: @LGT the only js code are those at the moment. The div is not made dynamically, and I have .ready function which is supposed to hide it at page load. An alert there keeps popping up everytime the page loads but something happens after it is hidden I suppose.

Comment: Why don't you set the default style of the div to 'none' instead of hiding it every time with js?

Comment: If that alert is a window, it's done by JS? Code that breaks could be included too, doesn't have to be something you wrote on this page. (Check your error console.)

Comment: @user986959 that does work indeed. I have to do a bit more juggling to do a simple toggle though. I am still stuck at why the hide() doesn't actually hide the element on second load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `data_ajax="true"` to your `Html.BeginForm` it will operate like `Ajax.BeginForm`. That means your form submission is happening via ajax and the page *is not being reloaded*. You are just reloading the contents of the page/form.

That means `$(document).ready()` will not fire a second time as that is an Ajax load and not a page load.

Options:

- remove `data_ajax="true"`
- listen for the ajax load completion and hide the div at that point
- **hide the div in the first place with styling (preferred)**